# concat arrays with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that are made up of 20 arrays of objects. Like this:

```
var array1 = [
  [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ],
  [
    {'x':1,'y':1},
    {'x':1,'y':1}
  ],
...
  [
    {'x':19,'y':19},
    {'x':19,'y':19}
  ]
];

var array2 = [
  [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ],
  [
    {'x':1,'y':1},
    {'x':1,'y':1}
  ],
...
  [
    {'x':19,'y':19},
    {'x':19,'y':19}
  ]
];
```

I want the end result to be:

```
[
    [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
    ],
...
];
```

So I'm attaching two items in each array, meaning each array should contain four objects now.

What I tried was:

```
      var array3 = array1;

      array3.forEach(function(item,i) {
         item.concat(array2[i])
      })
```

But nothing was appended

### Question

Is there a less painstaking approach to concat items iteratively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a fairly typical "zip" operation, can can be accomplished using `map`.

```js
var array1 = [
  [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ],
  [
    {'x':1,'y':1},
    {'x':1,'y':1}
  ],
  [
    {'x':19,'y':19},
    {'x':19,'y':19}
  ]
];

var array2 = [
  [
    {'x':0,'y':0},
    {'x':0,'y':0}
  ],
  [
    {'x':1,'y':1},
    {'x':1,'y':1}
  ],
  [
    {'x':19,'y':19},
    {'x':19,'y':19}
  ]
];

var result = array1.map( (item,i) => item.concat(array2[i]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 9):

[`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is not mutating the original array which means it creates a new instance of array.

Therefore, you need to assign concatenated array to the original value.

```
  var array3 = array1;

  // If you don't want to mutate 'array1, use spread operator like following:
  // var array3 = [...array1];

  array3.forEach(function(item,i) {
     array3[i] = item.concat(array2[i])
  })
```

Comment: This will mutate `array1`

Comment: @adiga You're totally right. Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 5):

If you assign `var array3 = array1` and mutate `array3`, it will change `array1` as well because they are both referencing the same array.

You could `map` the first array and `concat` each inner array based with that of  `array2` based on the index

```
const array3 = array1.map((o, i) => o.concat(array2[i]))
```

or in ES5:

```
var array3 = array1.map(function(o, i) {
  return o.concat(array2[i])
})
```

```js
const array1=[[{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0}],[{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],[{x:19,y:19},{x:19,y:19}]],
    array2=[[{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0}],[{x:1,y:1},{x:1,y:1}],[{x:19,y:19},{x:19,y:19}]];

const array3 = array1.map((o, i) => o.concat(array2[i]))

console.log(array3)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
var array3 = array1.map((a, idx) => [...a, ...array2[idx]] )
```

Comment: Please do not just post the code, but also explain what it is doing and give give hints what to look for in order to understand it better, in this case: "spread operator".